# React-intl: FormttedMessage wont display 0 but it will display any number

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-intl

I have a list and I need to display no. of elements in the list. I used `<FormattedMessage>` and everything works great but when the list size is `0`, the `<FormattedMessage>` displays nothing. It works for negative(if I hardcode it) and for positive(if the list has members), but in case of 0 nothing is displayed.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {FormattedMessage} from 'react-intl'

class List extends Component {

  render() {

    let userNumber=0;
    if(this.props.list.get('users').size > 0){
      userNumber = this.props.list.get('users').size;
    }
    else{
      userNumber = 0;
    }

    console.log(userNumber)
    console.log(typeof userNumber)
    return (
          <FormattedMessage
            id = 'active-users'
            description = 'ACTIVE USERS'
            defaultMessage = 'ACTIVE USERS ({userList})'
            values = {{
              userList: userNumber
            }}
          />
      )
  }
}

export default List
```

Comment: paste complete code, what is the only else at the end doing. and also what is his.props.list.get('users') returning?

Comment: I'll edit, it was that if list is empty there is a spinner, else it displays the active users. I removed the Spinner code. Also i've edited it correctly now

Comment: @ThunderBird checkut now

Comment: what does his.props.list.get('users') return ?

Comment: Ordered map of list of users.

Comment: Anyway it doesnot depend on that. If I comment that `if else` part out. Then also I cant display 0, if i change that to any other, it displays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix that using `'ACTIVE USERS ({userList, number})'` instead of `'ACTIVE USERS ({userList})'`

```
<FormattedMessage
        id = 'active-users'
        description = 'ACTIVE USERS'
        defaultMessage = 'ACTIVE USERS ({userList, number})'
        values = {{
          userList: userNumber
 }}/>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d0hypvtz/14/)

Comment: cool. It works. Documentation of react-intl is good, but it need to be better. Thanks man